# Can't set value after using explode()

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, delimiter, explode

I can't set value in the variables `$nombre`, `$apellidos`, `$genero`, `$fecha_nacimiento`, `$ruta_obtenida` and these errors are displayed:

> Undefined offset: 1
>   Undefined offset: 2
>   Undefined offset: 3
>   Undefined offset: 4

When I print the values with echo the values are correctly displayed, but when I assign them to the variables, it does not work. Why is this happening?

```
$nombre = $apellidos = $genero = $clave1 = $clave2 = $fecha = $ruta = "";

$usuarioModel = new perfildatosModelo($_SESSION['el_correo']); 
$a_users = $usuarioModel->get_usuario_info($_SESSION['el_correo']); 
$count = 0; 

$pieces = explode("#", $a_users); 

foreach($pieces as $element): 
    $pieces = explode("|", $element);   
    $count++;  
    $nombre=$pieces[1]; 
    $apellidos=$pieces[2]; 
    $genero=$pieces[3]; 
    $fecha_nacimiento=$pieces[4];         
    $ruta_obtenida=$pieces[0];  
endforeach;
```

Comment: Show `$a_users` and/or the first exploded `$pieces`.

Comment: This is clearly because of data not being present. can you provide data available in `$a_users` for a clear idea

Comment: Re assigning peices inside loop, rename it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop (while I personally wouldn't be reusing the `$pieces` variable name inside the loop) works as intended.  I have a strong suspicion that you have a leading or trailing `#` that is messing with your process.  (I wouldn't have to guess if you provided some sample input)  Look at this [demonstration](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/28b3aae0fbb1a79bc1f8a6662d43cc10ee5637e8):

```
$a_users='#ro2|no2|ap2|ge2|fn2#';

// A potential problem with exploding on a string with a leading or trailing #
$pieces = explode("#", $a_users);  // first element is empty string, second holds values, third is empty string

foreach($pieces as $element){
    $pieces = explode("|", $element);
    $nombre=$pieces[1]; 
    $apellidos=$pieces[2]; 
    $genero=$pieces[3]; 
    $fecha_nacimiento=$pieces[4];         
    $ruta_obtenida=$pieces[0];
    echo "nombre = $nombre\n";
    echo "apellidos = $apellidos\n";
    echo "genero = $genero\n";
    echo "fecha_nacimiento = $fecha_nacimiento\n";
    echo "ruta_obtenida = $ruta_obtenida\n\n";
}
```

This throws two batches of the same Undefined offset Notices that you are experiencing because of the leading and trailing `#`.  To fix this, you can use something like this: `$a_users=trim($a_users,'#');` before exploding on `#`.

---

While your method will work on properly `#`delimited strings, a better / more concise approach would be to avoid the loop altogether and define your variables with [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

If there is any danger of the pieces data not being complete, include a check that your `$pieces` string has enough `pipe` characters to deliver the expected number of values for your set of variables.  Otherwise, you can omit the condition and move directly to `list()`.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0482e91af472633b66a10918645586383d90f128))

```
$a_users='ro1|no1|ap1|ge1#ro2|no2|ap2|ge2|fn2';
$valid_pieces_count=0;
foreach(explode('#',$a_users) as $pieces){
    if(substr_count($pieces,'|')!=4){
        echo "Something went wrong, insufficient components in $pieces\n\n";
    }else{
        list($ruta_obtenida,$nombre,$apellidos,$genero,$fecha_nacimiento)=explode('|',$pieces);
        echo "nombre = $nombre\n";
        echo "apellidos = $apellidos\n";
        echo "genero = $genero\n";
        echo "fecha_nacimiento = $fecha_nacimiento\n";
        echo "ruta_obtenida = $ruta_obtenida\n\n";
        ++$valid_pieces_count;
    }
}
echo "valid_pieces_count = $valid_pieces_count";
```

Output:

```
Something went wrong, insufficient components in ro1|no1|ap1|ge1

nombre = no2
apellidos = ap2
genero = ge2
fecha_nacimiento = fn2
ruta_obtenida = ro2

valid_pieces_count = 1
```